# how to reuse ui-grid external pagination and sort methods?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to use ui-grid with external pagination and external sort in a project. how can i modify ui-grid once and use it several place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, in this case any modifications are not required :) But answering to your question [forking `ui-grid` repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) would be perfect. And you can still use `bower` :)

`ui-grid` is able to handle sorting and pagination with only config object. I'm using `ui-router` as well to modify page URL with current page number or name of the sorted column.

I mixed up two examples from the docs - external sorting and external pagination, to show them both working together.

So if you want to re-use it in easy way, just make a service or simple decorator.

Cheers!

http://plnkr.co/edit/XD06tjcTQsg6YiWpjRsN?p=preview